# Offline batch-conversion of HEIC to JPG while preserving metadata (EXIF)

Tags: open-source, image-processing, exif, jpg, heif

I am looking for an offline (open source) software application with GUI that is capable of

1. batch-converting [HEIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) files from Apple devices to [JPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) files with good (and adjustable) quality
2. keeping all possible metadata in [EXIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif)

I tried (proprietary) [FonePaw HEIC Converter](https://www.fonepaw.com/heic-converter/) but metadata are missing in circa 50% of cases (even when I can see them in original HEIC files using Windows Photos Viewer). I use Windows 10 or Linux (recent Ubuntu).

Comment: Do you want to keep in EXIF QuickTime part?

Answer (score 2):

I just published a Windows application that I wrote to handle offline batch processing of `.heic` files to `.jpg` or `.png`.  It's free and has no restrictions on how many images you can process.

I'm not a winforms guru so please be kind if you decide to try it out!

Please note that it is for Windows only.  You can find the site here:
https://sites.google.com/view/heicconverter/home

Answer (score 1):

You can try **GIMP** with Batch process on recent Ubuntu.

I had two errors with GIMP but the `.HEIC` files are converted to `.JPG`. Not sure if all metadata are preserved. Some will change for sure (info depending of file format). If it doesn't work for all metadata you can try `exiftool` (command line) to overwrite metadata in bulk to the `.JPG` files (converted by GIMP or another software) from the `.HEIC` files. You can also try `ImageMagick` from command line to convert.

Errors I had :

```
Execution error for procedure 'gimp-image-attach-parasite':
'gimp-comment' parasite validation failed: comment contains invalid UTF-8

Plug-in crashed: "dbp"
# DBP = (David's Batch Processor)
(/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/dbp)
```

To install GIMP and the plugins

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

If you don't already have GIMP installed

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

For Batch process and other plugins

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```

In GIMP menu (after installing gimp-plugin-registry) you go to

- Filters/Batch/Batch process
- Add files
- You select all your `.HEIC` files and click on Add.
- Then click Close
- Click Ouput
- Select Format : `JPG`
- Adjust Quality
- Then click Start

[image: GIMP Input]

[image: GIMP Output]

Note : I'm not a specialist in image format, but I think even at 1,00 Quality for `.JPG`, you will lose resolution from `.HEIC`. Maybe `.PNG` is a better choice, depending of what you want. Files will be larger in `.PNG`. Make tests with some files.

Answer (score 1):

[iMazing HEIC Converter](https://imazing.com/converter) is a free utility (available for both Windows and Mac) that can batch-convert HEIC photos to JPEG or PNG format. Just install and run the program, then open an Explorer window containing your HEIC files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on macOS there's a built-in command-line utility named `sips` which can do the conversion. I can also confirm that it correctly preserves metadata when going between HEIF and JPEG.

There are [some examples on how to use sips on the Apple StackExchange, including bulk conversion scripts.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410920/328778)